# Could A Dragon Really Survive Given the Right Conditions?

Tags: biology, physics, flight

So I have been trying to design a dragon that is somewhat realistic and I wanted to see if it was plausible in the our real world, despite dragons being very unrealistic. I also wanted to know what its metabolic rate would be or daily energy requirements as I have a hard time finding a consistent metabolic rate. So here is the background of the dragon.

- 21 Feet(6.4 Meters) Long
- 42 Foot(12.8 Meter) Wingspan
- 10 Foot(3 Meter) Wing Cord
- Weighs 1300 lbs(589 Kg)
- Wing Loading: 18Kg/m2
- Diet would Include: Fish, Birds, Yak, Elk, Deer, Sheep, Goat, Caribou, Moose, Muskox, Bears.

The dragon would be more similar to a bird than a reptile but is also similar to a pterosaur.
So would it be plausible for a dragon with these conditions above to sustain itself in a mountainous environment?

Comment: More than from wingspan and weight, the metabolic rate is influenced by the type of animals your dragons belong to. Are they mammals, reptiles, something else? Also please ask 1 question per post, as per our [help]. And a small nitpick: bones as in skeleton components are not prey.

Comment: The weight is probably way too high to allow for flight. Even the largest pterosaurs are thought to be < 600 lbs, and they were about the size of a giraffe.

Comment: to add to the previous poster those 6-700lb pterosaurs had a 32 ft wingspan. I suggest working out the anatomy first, there are several preexisting questions along those lines. then asking about hte ecology.

Comment: Maybe I'm mis-remembering something. But didn't pterosaurs live during an era with higher O2 content in the atmosphere? It let them run "hotter." Lots of other very large fauna like 5 foot butterflies and such were possible because of that. I don't have a cite for it. Maybe a dragon could be possible in a 70% oxygen atmosphere. Don't use that flame breath!

Comment: @puppetsock no the O2 content of the atmosphere changed drastically during the time pterosaurs were dominant. this included O2 higher and lower than now. Pterosaurs ruled the skies for a loooong time.

Comment: Another condition you could change to make a "giant flier" more plausible is lowering the force of gravity.  If Middle-Earth (or whatever fantasy world) exerts less than 1G, larger creatures can get off the ground.

Answer (score 4):

The largest animal ever, quetzalcoatlus, is estimated to have weighted around 250 kg, less than half of your dragon, and they had a similar wingspan to your creature, so the first problem here is their weight and size.

The main issues with Dragons as they're classically depicted in media are that

1- they need to be relatively heavy due to having an extra pair of fully functional limbs, which, when considering their ability to essentially match land predators in durability means they also need to be sturdy. The single fact that your dragon hunts elk means that, unless it's using a pack hunting method (which doesn't seem to be the case due to the sheer size of the animal) would mean it's at least as sturdy as a siberian tiger, a creature that, without a pair of powerful wings or flight muscles, can already weight 210 kg despite being only a third of your dragon's length.

2-they're big, very big, and if azdarchids, the largest family of flying animals we know of, is anything to go by, growing big without sacrificing flight requires heavy adaptations to eliminate as much weight as possible. Your muscles make you heavier? Have legs only strong enough to support your weight and use your wing muscles to quad launch into the air. The tail is weighting you down without adding anything useful for flight? Get rid of it altogether or have it vestigial. This can be very well seen in raptors, who have both strong legs and wings (something a bit closer to what you'd expect from a wyvern). One of the strongest raptors is the harpy eagle, who feeds on monkeys, has a grip supposedly stronger than a Rottweilers' bite and... is no bigger than a human child. Harpy eagles, despite being a very powerful bird, will not grow much larger than a meter tall. That is not to say however that it's not capable of messing up a human who threatens its nest, as they can deliver powerful blows.

So, in other words, one thing commonly seen in nature is: the bigger you get, the heavier you need to be. The heavier you are the harder it becomes to fly. A very large dragon, regarding an earth like planet in terms of gravity and atmospheric composition, wouldn't be able to be bulky, and a more bulkier dragon wouldn't be able to grow as much without compromising flight.

That is not to say however, that a creature who isn't as built to "tank" attacks as you'd see in terrestrial predators can't rise to the top: Meet [hatzegopterix thambema](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5248582/), probably one of the coolest ahzdarchids to have ever existed. Why? Because it lived around hatzeg Island, a place with no large theropod carnivores to compete with, meaning it was able to specialize into something closer to an Apex predator, developing a stockier build and feeding on the small inhabitants of the island, being probably the best real example of a very large flying Apex predator. Hatzegopterix was around 6 meters high and has a wingspan expected to be around 12m, although these can be considered as conservative estimates.

So I'd say that the 2 main things to make your dragon more believable without making it too different from what you'd expect from such a creature are:

1-make it smaller. Modern eagles are already a great example of how possible it is to take down animals larger than your own even if they're not built to fly like you are. Given that a siberian tiger is 2 meters long and easily capable of taking down elk, having a 2.5 m long dragon would already allow you to distribute their weight better, meaning the same 250 kg could be used to make a smaller, but more powerful animal.

2-have it live on an island or in a location in which competition with large, fully terrestrial animals is minimal or non-existent. That would allow your dragon to maintain a position of Apex predator without also having to share its food sources with other animals who did not evolve to be lighter and more adapted to fly. It'd also mean that they could still survive and thrive with a less sturdy build, again allowing them to redistribute their weight for a more flight directed build.

3- if possible, make it a wyvern. The main problem with extra fully developed limbs is that they add weight, and a 6 limbed animal would always be heavier than the same animal with 4 limbs unless we're talking bout atrophied limbs (and even then). If vampire bats and pretosaurs are anything to go by, it's possible to use your wings to jump into the air, meaning you don't need your legs to be as muscular as a bird would need, and so I'd say that it'd be better for your dragon to concentrate the weight, muscle and bone of 4 weaker legs into 2, more powerful ones.

I'm no specialist on mountains, but I do know that the higher you go, the less oxygen you have available. Given that andean condors exist I think it's not impossible, but I'd still recommend you to have a dragon island rather than a dragon mountain, regarding the examples we have of large flying predators that already lived in our planet during the past. Being large can be a problem, because you need more food, it makes it harder to fly and it means you have to sacrifice a lot of things just to stay light enough to support yourself in the air. A creature as large as a siberian tiger flying in your direction not only sounds much more realistic than a 6 meter long flying behemoth, it also still sounds plenty enough scary.

Comment: Largest winged flying animal. Not the largest ever. Cheese and crackers there have been humans that topped 250kg.  https://www.guinnessworldrecords.com/news/2018/12/history-of-heaviest-humans-as-worlds-biggest-man-loses-half-his-body-weight-550495#:~:text=The%20Heaviest%20man%20ever%20was,%3B%2069%20st%209%20lb).

Comment: @puppetsock I'm assuming you mean that 250 kgisn't the absolute heaviest a flying animal can be, but I didn't want to go into too much speculation regarding this topic, so I stuck to real examples of large flying animals we have.

Comment: Maybe it's possible to go above 250 kg, but not through natural means (read: evolution)... I have to give some thought to it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I honestly didn’t really undertake that much research so I appreciate your response even if this dragon exists in a magic world, I wanted to see if it was possible given real life conditions so THANK YOU!!

Comment: Also no offense but I wanted to mention that not only pack animals hunt caribou for example bears or wolverines but other than everything else you said is very helpful

Comment: @Hello that's a mistake I've already fixed, I wrote caribou instead of elk in my answer for whatever reason. The reason why I compared your dragon to siberian tigers is precisely because they're large solitary predators who hunt elk, much like your dragon seemed to be. I meant it wasn't likely that your dragon would need the help of a pack to hunt an elk on its own, since it was so large.

Comment: That’s Alright I really do appreciate your answer it helps out a lot cause even though I would like to make a realistic dragon, Dragons don’t fit with our world and would require many modifications to survive. Thank you though

Comment: @Hello I highly recommend you to search for questions regarding dragons in this se, because believe it or not, there's quite a few people here trying to make dragons work out realistically in our world. Maybe some of them can serve as good inspiration for your own project.

Answer (score -1):

A dragon could absolutely survive under the right conditions. Those conditions are being considerably smaller than what is often depicted in fiction.

As it turns out, even fire breathing could be justified scientifically; It would use a chemical reaction like one of these:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hDct3tV12Ns

Presumably, hydrogen gas and possibly a bit of sticky bile would be produced in a bodily sac, similar in structure to the stomach. The dragon would expel the gas at high speeds, and a gland on the mouth would use one of the aforementioned chemical reactions to ignite the gas.

If the dragon used this ability to cook food before eating it, It might be able to get more calories from fewer prey than it would otherwise.

However, it is simply too difficult for a giant creature like a dragon to produce enough lift to get off the ground. The giant pterosaurs got around this by having extremely weird body proportions; pteranodon had a 7-meter wingspan, but it's body was no bigger than that of a turkey. A dragon, with it's much more proportional build, could not get into the air without some sort of non-biological boost. Perhaps it has magic scales that help push air downward?

Comment: Pteranodon's was a lot bigger than turkeys, its bigger than yours in many dimensions. the firebreathing answer is good however, although you may want to consider peroxides instead like bombardier beetles easier to make and store.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, even though the dragon is a modified version of a dragon in a magical world I just wanted to see if it could work THANK YOU!!!

Comment: @john Perhaps I should have specified "Torso"? looking at this scale image, and this picture of a downed turkey, the body section appears to be roughly the same size, even if the pteranodon's head, neck, and wings are much larger: https://twitter.com/Globin347/status/1351990819641692161?s=20

Comment: ...Then again, maybe I misjudged the size based on the turkey's large feathery tail.

Comment: Keep in mind on a turkey a LOT of that size is feathers.